# Ember.js - How can I transition to another route from an initialiser?

Tags: ember.js, socket.io, ember-cli, engine.io

I am using an initialiser to connect to a socket server. After a set amount of time I would like to redirect to another route (which handles the error).

How can I do this from the initialiser?

Current Code Below:

```
/* Socket Initializer */
export default {
    name:   'Socket',
    initialize: function(Container, Application) {

        Application.deferReadiness();       

        var IO = Container.lookup('socket:main');

        IO.connect({
            reconnectionDelayMax: 1000
        });


        IO.socket.on('connect', function(){
            Application.advanceReadiness();
        });


        var RetryCounter = 0;

        IO.socket.on('connect_error', function(Error) {

            if (RetryCounter == 2) {


                //this.transitionTo('development');
                //Application.transitionTo('development');
                //Container.transitionTo('development');

                // None of the above work.

            }
            RetryCounter++;  
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the router from the container and call transitionTo from it.

```
var router = container.lookup('router:main');
router.transitionTo('foo');
```

Contrived Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bukuvuho/3/edit

Comment: This looks like it would work but I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: When I set it to go to a route I don't have (foo) it says: "Foo" route not found. When I set it to go to a route which I do have (test) it gives the above error. The test route is defined in the router.

Comment: Do you think you can reproduce with the example I've given, I'm not sure if I can guess what the issue is.

Comment: If I run the transition afterRender it works. I guess the router hasn't fully kicked in at the stage I wanted to use it.
Nevertheless, you have answered the question and I know have a solution. Thank you!